# Flattening a List with RxJava

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, flatten, rx-android

I am trying to convert flatten a List using Rx. Heres the current code:

```
rxflatten(treeList).subscribe(new Action1<List<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List<Object> objects) {
                Log.d("test", "original= " + treeList + " flattened=" + objects) ;
            }
        });


public static Observable<Object> rxflattenmylist(List<?> list) {
       return Observable.from(list)
                .flatMap(item -> item instanceof List<?> ? rxflattenmylist((List<?>) item) : Observable.just(item));
    }

 public static Observable<List<Object>> rxflatten(List<?> list) {
        return rxflattenmylist(list)
                .toList();

    }
```

This is the first data set

```
private static List<Object> a(Object... a) {
        return Arrays.asList(a);
    }

List<Object> treeList = a(a(1), 2, a(a(3, 4), 5), a(a(a())), a(a(a(6))), 7, 8, a());
```

Using this dataset, the following output is produced:

> original= [[1], 2, [[3, 4], 5], [[[]]], [[[6]]], 7, 8, []] flattened=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Here is a second dataset

```
private Object[] mNestedArrays = new Object[] {
            new Object[] { new Integer[] { 1, 2 }, new Integer[] { 3, 4 }},
            new Integer[] { 5, 6 }
    };

 List<Object> treeList = Arrays.asList(mNestedArrays);
```

I was trying to do the same using the above dataset, but instead of flattening, it only emits the top 2 items (an Object and Integer array).

Here is the output for this dataset:

> original= [Ljava.lang.Object; flattened=[[Ljava.lang.Object;, [Ljava.lang.Integer;]

So how would I flatten the second dataset using RxJava?

Thanks!

Comment: In what way does your Java 8 example code **seem** to work? I ran it, and it doesn't flatten your *input*.

Comment: Your right, it doesn't. I was using a different data set with the Java 8 version, I'll update my post to reflect that. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've altered the question a bit after playing some more with it, and eliminated the part of the question referring to Java 8's Streams.

Comment: As I understand, your `Arrays.asList(mNestedArrays)` produce a `List` of `Array`'s with two elements. Not a `List` of `List`'s. That's why `instance of List` won't work on nested elements.